# jmx connection timeout exception tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7, jmx

My tomcat in production stopped all of a sudden, exception in console.out  is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

jmxlisterner is enabled for tomcat, not sure what might have caused this , appreciate any  advice on this. Here full stack  trace.

```
Jun 01, 2014 6:17:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start 
INFO: Server startup in 49114 ms 
Jul 21, 2014 11:19:17 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop 
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-10001: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=10001] throws 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498) 
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:388) 
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:360) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 

Jul 21, 2014 11:19:58 AM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop 
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-1099: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=1099] throws 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498) 
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:388) 
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:360) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 

Jul 21, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor run 
SEVERE: Socket accept failed 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60) 
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:219) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 

Jul 21, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await 
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: accept: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out 
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530) 
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:452) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:778) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:724) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322) 
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456) 

Jul 21, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause 
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 
Jul 21, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause 
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 
Jul 21, 2014 11:20:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal 
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
```

Comment: Its a bug in tomcat 7  and fixed in 7.0.55 https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56684